# Wordpress Registry Error: Usernames can only contain letters, numbers, - and @

Tags: wordpress, utf-8, registration, buddypress, tr

I used wordpress, **buddpress plugin** for user account. But an error occurs with the username during registration:

```
Usernames can only contain letters, numbers, - and @.
```

**For example:** Rustu (OK) / Rüştü (Not OK)

May be add a filter for Turkish characters (utf-8), to be able to use *'I ğ ü'* etc in the username...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this piece of code in your theme's functions.php or you can use this in a plugin if you want. This will enable users to register using non-ansi characters.

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_user', 'sanitize_user_username', 3, 3);

function sanitize_user_username($username, $raw_username, $strict) {
    $username = $raw_username;
    $username = strip_tags($username);
    $username = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '', $username);
    $username = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $username);

    if ( $strict )
        $username = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9 _.\-@\x80-\xFF]|i', '', $username);
    $username = preg_replace('|\s+|', ' ', $username);

    return $username;
}
```